# Why does appending to NSTextView dramatically increase CPU usage on Mac

Tags: appkit, nstextview, xamarin.mac

Feel free to skip the background and jump straight down to TLDR (code).

**Background:**
I have a Xamarin.Mac app, though the crux of it is likely more to do with AppKit. I receive string messages from a websocket, which I add to a blocking collection, and this triggers a re-render of the `NSTextView`. In the re-render I try-get each string from the collection and add it to a single string with new lines, which I then append to the `NSTextView`'s `TextStorage.MutableString`.

**TLDR (code):**

```
// This is the custom rendered for my control, which is a NSTextView within a NSScrollView.
// The purpose is to serve as a log of all messages from the websocket,
// much like the Application Output pane in Visual Studio.
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged
    (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if(e.PropertyName == ScrollableTextView.LastUpdatedProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        var lines_str = "";
        string line;
        // this.Element.Lines is a BlockingCollection<string>,
        // which gets added to with messages received from the websocket.
        while (this.Element.Lines.TryTake(out line))
        {
            // Do other stuff with line, but have left it out for brevity.
            // Have confirmed it does not affect CPU usage.
            lines_str += line + "\n";
        }

        var ns_lines_string = new NSMutableAttributedString(lines_str);
        // Leaving out the bit where actual attributes are added to ns_lines_string for brevity.
        // Have confirmed it does not affect CPU usage.

        _textView.TextStorage.BeginEditing();
        // THIS BIT IT IS THE CULPRIT.
        _textView.TextStorage.Append(ns_lines_string);
        _textView.TextStorage.EndEditing();

        // Other stuff, left out for brevity.
        // Have confirmed it does not affect CPU usage.

        // Adjust scroll point.
        var visible_bottom = RectangleFExtensions.GetMaxY(_textView.VisibleRect());
        var actual_bottom = RectangleFExtensions.GetMaxY(_textView.Bounds);
        var should_scroll = visible_bottom == actual_bottom;

        if (should_scroll)
        {
            var end_of_text_range = new NSRange(_textView.String.Length, 0);
            _textView.ScrollRangeToVisible(end_of_text_range);
        }
    }
}
```

**Observations:**

1. Interestingly enough, if I `Console.WriteLine(message)`, Visual Studio for Mac prints each message, but does not appear to significantly increase its CPU usage.
2. If I resize the application window while it's running, CPU usage jumps past 100% and stays there for a noticeable period (over a minute).

**Question:** 
What can I do to keep CPU usage down?

Comment: Have you tried other ways to append text like [Appending to NSTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14905156)?

Comment: Thx. I had a look. I don't know what `range` is meant to be in `if([textView shouldChangeTextInRange:range`, but I wrapped `appendAttributedString` within `beginEditing` and `endEditing` but it still does not make a difference. I've also added another observation regarding window resizing.

Comment: I've updated the code to include `beginEditing` and `endEditing`. I've also removed the 400ms wait time as this causes a problem, which is that if it's within this window, messages remain in the buffer until the next re-render is triggered, which could be after a noticeable period, during which it appears that log messages are not being printed.

Comment: Howm can we reproduce the issue? How often is `OnElementPropertyChanged` called and how many lines and characters is `lines_str`?

Comment: Roughly 50 times a second and each time, `this.Element.Lines` (the blocking collection) would have a new string added - can use "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" :)

Comment: Updating less often should help.